# Unable to get data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I am using this JSON link to access data now i want to access the place name if i hover my mouse over particular marker !

```
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=https%3A//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json%3Flocation%3D-33.8670522%2C151.1957362%26radius%3D5000%26types%3Dfood%26name%3Dharbour%26sensor%3Dfalse%26key%3DAIzaSyAYMqH361IS1S9SA4atjBPCDlLpJ4mr6Sw&callback=?', function (data) {
    var responseData = data.contents;
});

events: {
    mouseover: function (marker, event, context) {
        console.log(responseData.results[this].name)
    }
},
```

Comment: Declare your "var responseData" globaly in your script and then try

Comment: yeah i did still not working :( ! if i gove responseData.results[0].name then i am getting my results ! there is something wrong with passing data inside the results array

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: use an each loop on the response data

Comment: @SoftwareNerd : 
 
Could you help me to how to use that in my code ! i.e in this segment console.log(responseData.results[this].name)

Answer (score 0):

Here in you code **`this`** refers the `moverover` event.  So the problem is there also make `responseData`  as global variable.

**Updates:**

Here is a simple approach

```
var responseData = data.contents;
    var res = responseData.results;
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        console.log(res[i].name)
    }
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gmr4p/)

Comment: Could you help me to how to use that in my code ! i.e in this segment console.log(responseData.results[this].name)

Comment: Yea i can get name if i pass it through an for loop but my problem is if i mouseover on any marker the name of particular marker stored in JSON must be displayed !

Comment: @user2889942 check this http://jsfiddle.net/Gmr4p/1/  what you need is some where the index numbers.  you can even use data attribute

Comment: in my console,am getting typeerror:res[parseInt($(this).text())].name is undefined

Comment: @user2889942 definitely you will get undefined.  the reason is you're not using as I mentioned in fiddle.  You have marker generated by script.  Do not possible, try using data attributes

Answer (score 0):

here you can use loop like this

```
      $.each(responseData , function (index, value) {
            console.log(value.name)
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the return type of response data is something valid, I doubt using results[this] will lead to coherent data.

You should inspect what responseData.results contains to see what data you want to display (add 'debugger;' and inspect responseData.results).

```
var responseData;
$.getJSON('http://...', function (data) 
{
    responseData = data.contents;
});

events: 
{
    mouseover: function (marker, event, context) 
    {
        debugger; // remove after inspect responseData and extract the worthy data
        console.log(responseData.results)
    }
},
```